# Is there any way to override outgoing connections in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js

I wonder if there is any way to override all outgoing connections in NodeJS, as I'm writing an Electron application that needs to override outgoing connections that are made through the computer the application is running on.
If there is a way to do this in NodeJS, how do I?

Comment: Can you give an example of what external or outgoing connections mean? that to ignore them later.

Comment: As in literally *any* outgoing connections. I want to be able to interrupt the connection and modify it slightly and then continue said connection.